# Is CCTray open source?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I need to look into the CCTray source code. I can only find the link to download its setup online, is there any way to get its code?

Comment: why the downvote? So you just downvote without telling something?

Comment: I seem to have 'irked' the stack overflow team by adding (If I don't write this..) in the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCNet as a whole is open source and available on github here:
https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET

You can find sources for CCTray there as well.